# onMouseEnter event doesn't work when dragging elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events

`onMouseEnter` event does not work right when mouse is dragging some element (like links and images). You can check this below:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("ul li").forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("mouseenter", e => {
        alert("mouseenter")
    });
});
```

```css
a {
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

ul li {
    width: 20rem;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #909090;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">drag this on top of the items below</a>
<ul>
    <li>item 01</li>
    <li>item 02</li>
    <li>item 03</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The event you are looking for is [`dragenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragenter_event).

Comment: yes! its worked! thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually what you need is `dragenter` event. Please check this example.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("ul li").forEach(li => {
    li.addEventListener("dragenter", e => {
        console.log("mouseenter", e.target)
    });
});
```

```css
a {
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

ul li {
    width: 20rem;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #909090;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a class='link' href="https://stackoverflow.com">drag this on top of the items below</a>
<ul>
    <li>item 01</li>
    <li>item 02</li>
    <li>item 03</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are intentionally dragging the anchor over the list item you should be using  the drag and drop API.

[Document dragover event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragover_event)

Stackoverflow says "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code"
So you will have to visit the MDN page for jsfiddle example

Answer (score -1):

try `onmousedown` instead of `onmouseenter`

Comment: mousedown is triggered by clicking

Comment: @JefterRocha do you mean you want to trigger an alert whenever a mouse is OVER the element?

Comment: yep but doesn't work when the mouse is dragging elements

Comment: try ```onmouseover``` then